# Service not know and Connection failure via

Tags: ansible, openstack, openstack-nova

Please find the below attachment. I am working on the Ansible integration with OpenStack. While running with playbook I got the below connection failed error.

1. ) I am using nova_compute module in ansible. While running the ansible playbook it gave pyhton_novaclient module required. I installed the python_novaclient using pip.
   But after I ran the playbook, it gave the same python_novaclient required error.
2. ) After the installation of python_novaclient, nova command is working fine.
   I checked the below command

Root>nova --os-username admin --os-password MiracleIT --os-project-name admin --os-auth-URL http://192.168.8.25:5000/v3/ service-list

It gave below attached error
attachment: 2
[attachment 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzHHH.png)

3. ) I am using on os_server module in ansible. While working on the ansible playbook, it gave RegionOne (Inner Exception: problem with authorization parameters) error. I attached the screen shot.
   Attachment: 3

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer well. I did not enter the Controller IP into /etc/hosts file. 
After put the IP into the /etc/hosts My playbook create an instance in  Openstack and working fine.

Thank you.